# Hive Index Rebuild Fails

Tags: indexing, hive, hiveql

I have built a Hive Table with ORC stored format

```
create table temp.userinfo(user_id int, user_group int, user_type int)
    row format delimited fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' stored as ORC
```

Then I generate an index on the table

```
create index user_id_user on table userinfo(user_id) as 'COMPACT' with deferred rebuild
```

After the data has been loaded, I try to rebuild the index with hql as"

```
ALTER INDEX user_id_user ON userinfo REBUILD
```

But I get the error as

> ERROR when execute sql: 'Error while processing statement: FAILED:
>   Execution Error in org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask'
>   sql=ALTER INDEX user_id_user on userinfo REBUILD, args=None

I don't know how to figure out this error. 
Thank you sooooo much!

Comment: The `on table` is not correct.

Comment: You mean in the create index part? what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out. Since ORC has built its own index, I couldn't build index on ORC stored table. When I change my stored format as textfile, I can build indexes